# embed javascript inside body using wicket

Tags: wicket

There are a few solutions that I have seen but none of them worked for me. I am using Wicket 1.6

my wicket contains the following

```
WebMarkupContainer scriptLeaflet = new WebMarkupContainer("script_leaflet");
scriptLeaflet.add(new AttributeAppender("src", urlFor(new JavaScriptResourceReference(BasePage.class,"js/leaflet.js"), null).toString()));
add(scriptLeaflet);
```

my html contains the following

```
<script wicket:id="script_leaflet"></script>
```

I am using firefox's inspect element to check the content. I dont see any javascript in the rendered html page. If I replace the script tag with div tag just to see what happens I see the src url on the div tag as <div src="...."> but does not work when using the script tag

Comment: works fine here, with the <script> tag in the body and inside a <wicket:head>.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am trying to add it to the body and not the head

Comment: Why is it so important to add the script-tag to the body? If it works in the head...